# Is there a way to do some kind of overload to like basestring.__rshift__(self, other)

Tags: python-3.x, string, operator-overloading

I’m having trouble figuring out how to overload the >> operator for a string. If this can’t be done in this manner I will understand.
I’m using python 3.6
There are plenty of pages showing how I could do it if I wanted to set myclass << string, but I want to do it the other way around with string >>  myclass.
I’m having trouble finding reference material for the overload. 
Is there a way to do some kind of overload to like basestring.**rshift**(self, other) to get the result I’m looking for?

```
basestring.__rshift__(self, other):
    return other.doSomething(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you cannot add an operator to a builtin type like str.